# Does resque share class variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque

```
class ViewJob
  @@counter = 0
  def initialize
    ...
  end
end
```

Do all Resque job instances of this class share the same @@counter?  Or is there any other way to share variables in Resque jobs (I'm not a fan of global variables)?

Comment: so did you find Resque behaving different with class variables?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko , sorry for the late reply. Resque does share class variables in common cases, the reason I got confused is because I used docker image to hold Resque service (which I forgot to mention, my bad), and these docker images sometimes do not share the same physical memory, thus class variables are not always sharable.

Answer (score 1):

It is Ruby, thus class variables behavior would not differ in any way.

General rule of class variables - if you're not sure you know you are using class variable right - do not do that. Even if you **are** sure - you most likely **do not** need it.